# Desktop Doesn't Load After Login

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments

I am a new Ubuntu user who recently downloaded 18.04 to my desktop (modified with a SSD replacing the original harddrive) but the Ubuntu desktop doesn't load after I log in.

When the desktop fails to load, it stays either on the Ubuntu loading screen, switches to a flat purple screen, or goes completely black. If you leave it on for long enough, it will eventually go completely black.

I have tried re-installing it multiple times with a variety of different settings, but every time it fails.

I have, however, managed to get it to work properly a total of one time without doing anything (as if purely by chance!), but it fails to be reproducible. I have a Nividia graphics card if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: *I have a Nividia graphics card if that has anything to do with it* It has EVERYTHING to do with it! You need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers and if it isn't booting correctly with the open-source driver then you need to boot with `nomodeset`.

Comment: I found out how to add ```nomodeset``` and it does load the desktop now, thank you! But I am having other issues.

I need to clarify that I was wrong about my graphics drivers. They are Intel, not Nvidia. I also need to state that even though it gets to the desktop, my screen proportions are highly distorted and they do not work very well. Furthermore, the desktop will crash again after about 5 minutes of use.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by addiing "acpi=off" to the parameter "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" in file `/etc/grub/default`.

Then run `sudo update-grub`